# Trying to get a fallback for CSS3 transitions using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transition, fading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Special color transition effect with pure jQuery animation // no ui or other libary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349958/special-color-transition-effect-with-pure-jquery-animation-no-ui-or-other-lib)

I think this code *should* be it, but it's not working. I can tell it's changing the colors, but it's not *fading* (like CSS3 transitions). Please help. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav-wrap ul li a").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#444");
    });

    $("#nav-wrap ul li a").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("color","#999");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav-wrap ul li a").hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({color:'#444'}, 300);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({color:'#999'}, 100);
        }
    )}
});
```

This code require jQuery UI.

Comment: You know, animating colors do not work without the UI/UI.color module. You could at least add a note about it before people start complaining and downvoting. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to `animate()` the element, not simply to change the color value in css. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is a reference on how to do it.