# jQuery Background Fader on Load

Tags: jquery

I want that when people visit my website I want the  background to be white and when the page is fully loaded, after 5 seconds to start fading in a picture in the background and then after every 15 seconds fade to a new picture. Do you know a good way of doing this or if there are already some premade plugins etc.

Thanks,

Martijn

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) combined with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)?

You'll call two [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) functions within your [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function with different timers. Each of these will [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) the images by changing the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) using:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'YOURIMAGESRC');
```

Comment: But how can I change CSS in the body tag?

Comment: @MartijnR: Updated the answer, hope it helps. I would write it all out, but without seeing some code on your part I prefer not to. Please let me know if you need anymore help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use fadeIn() on the id of your img tag after 5 sec of loading. Run the counter to do the same on each 15 secs.

```
  <img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />
```

With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:

```
   $(window).load(function () {
      $('#book').fadeIn(15000, function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For color trasition effect, you need to use external plugin.

**[Here is jsFiddle to inspect.](http://jsfiddle.net/w75mN/20/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function repeat() {
        $('body')
            .delay(5000).animate({'background-color':'#fff'},1000)
            .delay(5000).animate({'background-color':'#000'},1000);
    }
    window.setInterval(repeat, 10000);

});
```

Color Transition Effect Source:
[Special color transition effect with pure jQuery animation // no ui or other libary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349958/special-color-transition-effect-with-pure-jquery-animation-no-ui-or-other-lib)

Comment: This is what I want but is it also possible without going back to the original background color and instead of using colours, using pictures?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 setTimout(function() {
  $('body').css("background-image","url('../img/background/1.jpg')").fadeIn(1000)
 },5000)
 
 function repeat() {
        $('body')
            .delay(5000).css("background-image","url('../img/background/2.jpg')").fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(5000).css("background-image","url('../img/background/3.jpg')").fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(5000).css("background-image","url('../img/background/1.jpg')").fadeIn(1000)
    }
    window.setInterval(repeat, 18000);
});

Comment: @MartijnR You can not animate background image like this. Divide your object 3 like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9DjML/14/ and you will be able to use fadeIn effect.