# How to animate background-color opacity on scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have two bits of code that I want to merge, but not sure on the actual correct markup and how to write it correctly.

```
function EasyPeasyParallax() {
  scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#header_nav').css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
      //'opacity': 0.5+(Math.min(scrollPos/100,1))
  });
};

$(function(){
  $('body').bind('mousewheel',EasyPeasyParallax);
});
```

The opacity selector works when I scroll down the page. However, I want to only target the background color of the div. How can I combine the 'background-color' selector with the scrollPos/100 code?

Comment: are you trying to change the actual color, or the opacity of the background color?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for animationg `background-color`'s `opacity` property on scroll event.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4a4CJ/14/)

```
function EasyPeasyParallax() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    var targetOpacity = 1;
    scrollPos < 1000 ? targetOpacity = '0.'+ (scrollPos*100)/10 : targetOpacity;
    $('span').css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, '+ targetOpacity +')'
    });
    console.log(scrollPos,targetOpacity);
};

$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        EasyPeasyParallax();
    });
});
```

-

If you want to animate `background-color` with jQuery, inspect this answer:

[Special color transition effect with pure jQuery animation // no ui or other libary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349958/special-color-transition-effect-with-pure-jquery-animation-no-ui-or-other-lib)

Comment: And if you seek good performance, only save the current scroll position in the scroll listener and make an additional RequestAnimationFrame loop that does the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function EasyPeasyParallax() {
            scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
            var opacityVal = 0.5+(Math.min(scrollPos/100,1));
            var rgbaCol = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + opacityVal + ')'
            $('#header_nav').css('background-color', rgbaCol);
        };
```